# SQLite error on releasing android-app with XAMARIN.NET and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, android-sqlite

I am working with VS 2017 and `XAMARIN/Android` and `SQLite`. In "debug" mode there is no problem. When i try to run the android "release" mode on the smart phone i become following error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Exception: Cannot create a table without columns (does 'SolarmonAndroidApp.Models.TicketPageModels.TicketType' have public properties?)

How can i properly configure the app to install the `SQLite_DB` on Android mobile phone.

Model:

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SolarmonAndroidApp.Models.TicketPageModels
{
    public class TicketType
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int _Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsFixed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Calls:

```
        _sql.CreateTable<TicketAction>();
        _sql.CreateTable<TicketType>();
        _sql.CreateTables<Park, Section, Ticket, User>();
        _sql.CreateTables<Row, Inverter, Number, Pool, Attachment>();
        _sql.CreateTable<CatchLog>();
        _sql.CreateTable<AppSettings>();
        _sql.CreateTables<TicketChecklist, TicketCheckpoint, SubTicket>();
```

Comment: i think the exception is pretty self explanatory, does your TicketType class from Models > TicketPageModelsm have public properties? post your class here so we can help

Comment: You need to post the code that gives you the error. We cannot help you otherwise. Maybe start by 1. How you try to create the table?, 2. How you defined the class for which you want to create the table?

Comment: it does not work only in release mode ?, i.e. does it work in debug mode ?

Comment: @bwt yes in debug mode no problem

Comment: What is the linking mode (project's Properties / Android Options / Linking ) ? Is it *Sdk and user assemblies* ?

Comment: @bwt yes, i can start the app, but after it tries to create tables it ends in an exception.

Comment: Change the linking mode to *Sdk assemblies only*

Comment: I am also betting on linking issue. Read up on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker It is possible your class isn't actually used anywhere, so it isn't compiled in release mode.

Comment: @bwt it makes no difference

Comment: did you try to clean / rebuild the solution, after changing the linker mode ?

Comment: @bwt thx,  "Sdk assemblies only" solved the problem, but i can not export as APK without other linkes. How can i export them properly?

Comment: You should be able to create an archive (APK) with any linker mode, the only difference is the size of the resulting APK. *Sdk assemblies only* is almost always the best choice : it preserve all of your code without creating huge APKs

Comment: @bwt  i can install the APK and it runs. But if i uninstall the app, i can not install the apk the second time. What it could be?

Comment: What error did you get when you install the apk the second time?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT "app not installed"

Comment: try to use adb (`adb install -r some.apk`) or to look in the logcat, you may have more details

Answer (score 1):

Comments recap :

It seems that the problem was linked (pun intended) to the [linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker). It is the part of the build process that tries to remove unused code, with the laudable goal of reducing the APK size, but is sometimes too aggressive.

This can be changed in the project's properties (for a release build) : *Android Options* tab, *Linker properties*.

The safest choice for *Linking* is *None* but it results in huge APKs, so it is usually only useful to check if build problem is related to the linking process.

The best choice is almost always *Sdk Assemblies Only* : All of your code is left untouched, and most of the unused code is removed.